How use "CanExecute" with event to command bevhavior from maui toolkit
I am using maui CommunityToolkit and I have good working (as I expect) button with CanExecute:
xaml:
<ImageButton Source="add.png" Command="{Binding LiftLevelUpCommand}" />

viewmodel:
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(LiftLevelUpCanExecute))]
private async Task LiftLevelUp()
{
    
    var newValue = LiftValue + sliderIncrement;
    if (newValue <= LIFT_MAX_VALUE)
    {
       LiftValue = newValue;
    } 
    
}

private bool LiftLevelUpCanExecute()
{
    return LiftValue < LIFT_MAX_VALUE;
}

And it works fine, when max LiftValue is reached the add.png button is disabled.
But I want to change behavior of this button with continusly pressed button like:
xaml:
<ImageButton Source="add.png">
    <ImageButton.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="Pressed"
            Command="{Binding LiftLevelUpCommand}"
        />
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Released"
            Command="{Binding ButtonReleasedCommand}"
        />
    </ImageButton.Behaviors>
</ImageButton>

viewmodel:
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(LiftLevelUpCanExecute))]
private async Task LiftLevelUp()
{
    _isButtonHolding = true;
    while (_isButtonHolding)
    {
        var newValue = LiftValue + sliderIncrement;
        if (newValue <= LIFT_MAX_VALUE)
        {
            LiftValue = newValue;
        } 
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
    }
}

[RelayCommand]
private void ButtonReleased()
{
    _isButtonHolding = false;
}

But when max value is reached the CanExecute doesn't work and button is still enabled. How can I fix it? How to use toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior with CanExecute.
I've tested in Android Emulator and Physical Android Device and bug exists in both.
When I've implemented it that way:
xaml: 

<ImageButton Source="add.png" Command="{Binding CanLiftLevelUpCommand}"> // added Binding
    <ImageButton.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="Pressed"
            Command="{Binding LiftLevelUpCommand}"
        />
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Released"
            Command="{Binding ButtonReleasedCommand}"
        />
    </ImageButton.Behaviors>
</ImageButton>

viewmodel:

[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(LiftLevelUpCanExecute))]
private void CanLiftLevelUp() // added
{
            
}

[RelayCommand]
private async Task LiftLevelUp()
{
    _isButtonHolding = true;
    while (_isButtonHolding)
    {
        var newValue = LiftValue + sliderIncrement;
        if (newValue <= LIFT_MAX_VALUE)
        {
            LiftValue = newValue;
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
    }
}

I've reached a partial what I exepect, I mean when the value reached max the LiftLevelUpCommand doesn't fire but button is still enabled.

May I know what platform you are using?

I am runing it in Android device, net8.0

Thanks for your update. I can reproduce the phenomenon as you described in your post. I don't think you can mix toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior with CanExecute. You may raise an issue or feature request on Github:https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/new/choose

Thanks, do you have nay ideas how to work around, using toolkit isn't necessary.

What do you mean change behavior of this button with continusly pressed button?

I want to have behavior such as: user pressed the button and as long as he pressed the [RelayCommand] is executing, when finger is released the [RelayCommand] for released should executed. I want to achived this with CanExecute, when LiftValue reached max the button should be disabled.

It looks like you're implementing a press-and-hold behavior for creating a repeatable action. It's probably worthwhile to apply a simpler refactor to your project so that the auto-repeat logic is in the refactored Button and not in your view model:

subclassed Button creating a RepeatButton (I recommend you subclass ImageButton)
invoke public event EventHandler Repeat and/or public ICommand? RepeatCommand
AutoRepeatDelay = 400ms
AutoRepeatInternal = 50ms
FinishedThresshold = 200ms (to guard against raising the event twice since clicked and released happen nearly at the same time)

// RepeatButton.cs
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace MauiRepeatButton;
public partial class RepeatButton : Button
{
    public static BindableProperty AutoRepeatDelayProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AutoRepeatDelay), typeof(int), typeof(RepeatButton), 400);
    public int AutoRepeatDelay
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(AutoRepeatDelayProperty);
        set => SetValue(AutoRepeatDelayProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty AutoRepeatIntervalProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AutoRepeatInterval), typeof(int), typeof(RepeatButton), 50);
    public int AutoRepeatInterval
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(AutoRepeatIntervalProperty);
        set => SetValue(AutoRepeatIntervalProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty FinishRepeatingThresholdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FinishRepeatingThreshold), typeof(int), typeof(RepeatButton), 200);
    public int FinishRepeatingThreshold
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(FinishRepeatingThresholdProperty);
        set => SetValue(FinishRepeatingThresholdProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty RepeatCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(RepeatCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(RepeatButton));
    public ICommand? RepeatCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(RepeatCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(RepeatCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public event EventHandler Repeat;

    private bool _isRepeating = false;
    public bool IsRepeating
    {
        get => _isRepeating;
        internal set
        {
            _isRepeating = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRepeating));
        }
    }

    private long _finishedTime = 0;
    public long FinishedTime
    {
        get => _finishedTime;
        internal set
        {
            _finishedTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FinishedTime));
        }
    }

    private CancellationTokenSource? Cts;

    public RepeatButton()
    {
        this.Pressed += RepeatButton_Pressed;
        this.Released += RepeatButton_Released;
        this.Clicked += RepeatButton_Clicked;
    }

    private async void RepeatButton_Clicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(AutoRepeatInterval);
        if (!IsRepeating || (DateTime.Now.Ticks - FinishedTime) <= FinishRepeatingThreshold * 10000)
        {
            return;
        }
        Repeat?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        if (RepeatCommand != null && RepeatCommand.CanExecute(null)) RepeatCommand?.Execute(null);
    }

    private void RepeatButton_Released(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cts?.Cancel();
    }

    private async void RepeatButton_Pressed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsRepeating = true;
        Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            Repeat?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            if (RepeatCommand != null && RepeatCommand.CanExecute(null)) RepeatCommand?.Execute(null);
            await Task.Delay(AutoRepeatDelay, Cts.Token);
            while (!Cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Repeat?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                if (RepeatCommand != null && RepeatCommand.CanExecute(null)) RepeatCommand?.Execute(null);
                await Task.Delay(AutoRepeatInterval, Cts.Token);
            };
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
        }
        IsRepeating = false;
        FinishedTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }
}

Here's how I use it:
<!--  MainPage.xaml  -->
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiRepeatButton.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiRepeatButton"
    x:Name="mainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0" Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                HeightRequest="185"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight"
                Source="dotnet_bot.png" />
            <Label
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                Text="Hello, World!" />
            <Label
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
                Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI" />
            <local:RepeatButton
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                RepeatCommand="{Binding Source={Reference mainPage}, Path=IncrementCounterCommand}"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Text="Click me" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

// MainPage.xaml.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
namespace MauiRepeatButton
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [RelayCommand]
        private void IncrementCounter()
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 1)
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
            else
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";
            SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
        }
    }
}


GitHub source: https://github.com/stephenquan/MauiRepeatButton
